# coniditons for integrability for log(X) where X is a r.v.?

Tags: logarithms, expected-value

Let $X$ be a positive random variable. I was thinking about if there exist a minimal condition to obtain
\begin{equation}
     \mathbb{E}(\log(X))<\infty
\end{equation}
of course if $X$ is defined to takes values on  an interval $[a,b]$ with $a,b>0$ the statement holds, but I think it is very restrictive. An example of what I am asking is: is there exist a $p$
such that $\mathbb{E}(X^p)<\infty$
implies that $log(X)$
has finite expectation? or anyone knows some weak conditions? Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: What if $X$ is gamma-distributed? The integral simply needs to converge.

Comment: If $X$ is gamma-ditribuited, both $X$ and $log(X)$ has finite expectation value. Of course the integral only needs to converge, but my question is in the direction: is there exist a $p$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X^p)<\infty$ implies that $log(X)$ has finite expectation?

Comment: $\log x$ is bounded above by $x^\alpha / \alpha$ for any $\alpha>0$.